# Meaning of Port and Dunnin

Tags: sentence-meaning

The following quote is from the Inception movie:

> Fischer: All right what's in the safe?
>
> Browning: Something for you.Fischer: Maurice always said it was his most precious 
>   gift to you. A will.
>
> Fischer: Maurice's will is with Port and Dunn.
>
> Browning: That's an alternate.
>
> Browning: This would supersede the other if you want it to.

A can't get the point of that `will` using as noun and `Port and Dunn`. Any ideas?

Comment: Port and Dunn would be a law firm. Maurice's last will and testament is being kept by them.

Comment: will - a legal document. The Last Will and Testament. it is used to pass an estate on to the person/people listed in the will. I haven't seen this movie, so I don't want to exactly answer this. Port and Dunn could be the recipients or the law firm that is 'enforcing' it.

Comment: If you didn't understand ***will** = Last Will and Testament*, how on earth were you going to understand what Browning goes on to say about an alternative will superceding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A will' is a legal document in which a person states who should receive his or her possessions after he or she dies.
"Port and Dunn" are names, maybe the name of a company.